# C# looping fileInfo causes CPU to work too much

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

**General background**

I have a need to watch 100's of files (which each weight around ~30KB). Thus, I came to conclusion that in order to preserve reliablilty, I cannot trust the `FileSystemWatcher` even when `InternalBuffer` increased to 64KB (due to file size and rapid file changes).

**Extra information**

The files are sent via a 3-rd party, this I cannot do anything else with the input such as receive the data via the database. What I can do, obviously, is to aggregate the file and do whatever I want with them.

Also, I need the handling the occur as close to the change time as possible.

**Code**

With that being said, I have created a small library which looks for changes within an interval.

The class looks like this:

```
public delegate void OnSingleFileModified(string filePath);
public delegate void OnFileError(Exception e);

public sealed class FolderMonitor :IDisposable
{
    private const int TimerInterval = 10000; 

    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, DateTime> _files;
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly string _pattern;

    private bool _start;

    public event OnSingleFileModified OnSingleFileModified;
    public event OnFileError OnFileError;

    public FolderMonitor(string folderPath, string pattern)
    {
        _start = true;
        _path = folderPath;
        _pattern = pattern;

        _files = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        MapFolder();

        _timer = new Timer(TimerInterval)
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Enabled = _start
        };
        _timer.Elapsed += CheckChanges;
    }

    private void MapFolder()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(_path))
            return;

        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path, _pattern);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            DateTime lastWrite = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file);
            _files[file] = lastWrite;
        }
    }

    private void CheckChanges(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs el)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(_path))
            return;

        try
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false; // prevents multithreating.

            IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path, _pattern);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                DateTime lastWrite = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file);

                // if file is new, add it and report
                if (!_files.TryGetValue(file, out DateTime prevLastWrite))
                {
                    _files[file] = lastWrite;
                    OnSingleFileModified?.Invoke(file); // OnFileCreate
                    continue;
                }

                if (lastWrite == prevLastWrite)
                    continue;

                // Change detected
                _files[file] = lastWrite;
                OnSingleFileModified?.Invoke(file); // OnFileModified

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OnFileError?.Invoke(e); // OnError
        }
        finally
        {
            _timer.Enabled = _start;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _start = true;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _start = false;
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The CPU consumption of this is 53% when this is wrapped inside a windows service.

**Suspicion**

Calling FileInfo on a path consumes lots of CPU.
New suspicion: The `Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path, _pattern);` is still resource consuming.

Any suggestions of how to resolve this? 
Thanks alot.

**EDIT**
new code.

Comment: If you have the timer fire less often, does CPU decrease?

Comment: Suspicion? You mean you haven't profiled your code? Why not? ("It runs in a service" is no excuse, just patch `Main` so it can run outside of a service.)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you don't want to use the FileSystemWatcher, and why you are explicitly avoiding threading? Seems like both would help here.

Comment: @mjwills no, i tried to change to 1000, also tried 30000. nothing seems to affect

Comment: A _very_ small optimisation you can do is to change `ContainsKey` to `TryGetValue` (which will avoid the need for one of the calls to `_files[info.Name];`).

Comment: @GalacticCowboy since I have lots of changing files and lots of new files coming every minute (mostly in specific times). FileSystemWatcher wont carry this.
Where am I avoiding threading? cause it probably wasn't on purpese

Comment: why are the files changing? your code looks good!, so i suspect that its a design flaw i.e. your modeling an unreal expectation. only way this can be determined is understanding what is happening and why, could you explain more of why the need is needed. Are you maybe able to move file to separate folders, to distinguish between new and existing. are you able to group by day or month.

Comment: @Seabizkit thanks. hmm..im affried that thats how the supplier works. and its one of the largest in the field :(

Comment: can you treat all files as new? think about that before you think im stupid....

Comment: @Seabizkit the problem i see in this approach is that whenever I get a file change event i parse it immediatly to understand what the change is. i think that parsing the entire file is way more resource consuming than FileInfo. or am i missing something?

Comment: I'm suggesting that treat all files that come in.as to be processed. instead of monitoring what has changed. Process each file as it arrives... and then archive it. its wouldn't make sense to keep checking hundreds of files. so I'm suggesting is process all files as they come in. this way the load is only what hasn't be processed, instead of looking to files to figure out what may have to process. I hope that makes sense, and you get what i mean, maybe the process doesn't allow for this.

Comment: @Seabizkit as i was saying, if change is detected, i have to parse the content of the file. this causes me to ask for data from database and manipiulate the file data against the data i had in my database.

Comment: wouldn't this happen away as then its modified... i.e. its changed and you would have to do this anyway?  it would still be quicker to use a new incoming list to find in an existing file in a directory than to scan all of them.

Comment: @Seabizkit well, every change causes this, yes. but iterating all the files doesnt actually suggest that everyone had changed. for example, there can be a file in the directory which wont change for a month, even a year.. so I dont want to even read it.

Comment: "LastWriteTimeUtc", i'm clearly unsure of when this is modified. I would of thought when the file gets written? aka when it arrives. Assuming I'm incorrect, you can still use the files  "LastWriteTimeUtc" and the file name to search for the file in the directory, if not found, then place in directory, if found then skip, you could structure your archive folder by your month and day to speed up the finding.

Comment: Im using GetLastWriteUTC from like 5 minutes ago. it doesnt seem to better the performance.
Regarding new files, if they are not exist in the dictionary, they are treated as new, of course, and just the LastWriteUTC is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try adding the pattern to the

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(_path);
```

statement, e.g.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(_path, _pattern);
```

You could also consider using the

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles()
```

method, in the same way.

```
string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path, _pattern);
```

as you can start working through them before the entire collection is returned.

Comment: Checking, Although im not sure that getting files names are the issue. gimme couple of minutes.

Comment: unfortunatly, no. it wont help

Comment: Thanks for the improvments, tho